# why does my my code not get executed after await

Tags: javascript

In my scraping code, the second console print never gets executed, I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong here, I'm new to the async and promises in javascript. ( the download picture function works )

```
async function scrape() {
  // ...
  await page.goto(URL, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });

  let picturetest = true;
  if (picturetest) {
    console.log("this gets printed");
    await downloadPictures(page);
    console.log("this never gets printer");
  }
}
// await browser.close();

scrape();

async function downloadPictures(page) {
  const elements = await page.$$(
    "body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) img"
  );
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    // get screenshot of a particular element
    await elements[i].screenshot({ path: `${i}.png`, quality: 100 });
  }
}
```

Comment: How many `elements` are in the array?  Does it setup through the loop at all? Are any files produced?

Comment: Hi matt yes it produces 4 images, that function works perfectly in isolation too.

Comment: you need error checking so that you can see what is going on in the code

Comment: are you redirecting or refreshing the browser after taking screenshot?

Comment: You need to somehow handle the promise. Usually with `await (do something).then(response => console.log(response)).catch(error => console.log(error))`

Comment: @PixAff you are right, i changed something tiny in my screenshot function added a config and it was throwing an error! works now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. The `downloadPictures` function is caught in an infinite loop
2. An exception is being thrown and is not being caught

Given that your loop looks fairly straightforward, you should focus on #2 first. Start by adding a top-level error handler, where you currently invoke `scrape()`:

```
scrape().catch((error) => { console.error(error); });
```

This may or may not reveal the problem. You can narrow in on it by adding try/catch blocks around the individual `await` lines:

```
try {
  await someAsyncCall();
} catch (error) {
  console.error('someAsyncCall failed', error);
}
```